# Eclipse maven build: how to include -P items

Tags: eclipse, maven

I want to setup a maven build in eclipse.  My command line build uses several -P items.  Where do you set these in the Eclipse 'Maven Build' run configurations dialogue?

Answer (score 0):

In the Main tab of your configuration, in the Profiles entry box.